# Pandas. Selecting rows with missing values in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have a dataframe with the columns `'Race', 'Age', 'Name'`. I want to create two 2 DF's:
1) Without missing values in columns `'Race' and 'Age'`
2) Only with missing values in columns 'Race' and 'Age'

I wrote the following code

```
first_df = df[df[columns].notnull()]
second_df= df[df[columns].isnull()]
```

However this code does not work. I solved this problem using this code

```
first_df= df[df['Race'].isnull() & df['Age'].isnull()]
second_df = df[df['Race'].isnull() & df['Age'].isnull()]
```

But what if there are 10 columns ? Is there a way to write this code without logical operators,  using only `columns` list ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If select multiple columns get `boolean DataFrame`, then is necessary test if all columns are Trues by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) or test if at least one True per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
first_df = df[df[columns].notnull().all(axis=1)]
second_df= df[df[columns].isnull().all(axis=1)]
```

You can also use `~` for invert mask:

```
mask = df[columns].notnull().all(axis=1)
first_df = df[mask]
second_df= df[~mask]
```

Comment: What is the difference betwen .all() and .any() ? Btw, thank you very much. Your solution works!

Comment: @RustemSadykov - all id like chain by `&` for AND, `any` is like chain by `|` for OR.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Make a new dataframe having dropped the missing data (NaN, pd.NaT, None) you can filter out incomplete rows.
DataFrame.dropna drops all rows containing at least one field with missing data

Assume new df as DF_updated and earlier as DF_Original

Step 2 : Now our solution DF will be difference between two DFs. It can be found by
pd.concat([DF_Original,DF_updated]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)